# How do I change the SQL executed for an SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2 with SSRS 2010. I'm testing a stored procedure that uses an if statement to switch between execution of one of 2 simple SQL statements. My ultimate goal is to replace SQL embedded in several SSRS reports with stored procedures that choose which statement to run based on a date parameter.

I tested the statement in SSMS and it switches between statements and produces results with no problem. However, in SSRS when I execute the report and test for the 2nd statement, except for a computed text column my result set is empty. If I run the same proc from the SSRS query designer the switch between statements executed works

Can anyone help me understand why the switch does not work when executing through the report? Here's the SQL I'm using:

```
begin
if @reportdate >='10/1/2014' goto convformat
if @reportdate <'10/1/2014' goto preconvformat
end

preconvformat:

SELECT TOP (1000) col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
    ,col5
    ,col6
    ,col7
    ,'t1' AS OriginalDataSource
FROM t1 AS arh WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN t1a1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON a.col1 = arh.col1
WHERE (arh.DateCreated < '1/1/2015')
and a.col2 = '12345678'

goto testend    

convformat:

SELECT TOP 1000 arcus.col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    ,col4
    ,col5
    ,col6
    ,col7
    ,'t3' AS OriginalDataSource
FROM t3. rmrtrk WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN t3t1 arcus WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON arcus.col1 = rmrtrk.col1

where customer_number = '12345678'

testend:
```

Comment: I've run into this issue when not specifying the database + schema in the Dataset definition.

Comment: To me this date seems a bit fishy `'10/1/2014'`, try using ANSI Date i.e `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure and use ANSI Date format to compare the passed date values ..

Also avoid using `GOTO`, very difficult to debug in larger pieces of code. Use `IF..ELSE` constructs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_Proc 
 @reportdate  DATE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (@reportdate >= '20141001')  --<-- ANSI Date Format  YYYYMMDD
   BEGIN
     -- 1st Statement 
   END
  ELSE
   BEGIN
    -- 2nd Statement 
   END

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what the problem is. Initially, I was going to use a union statement, where the 2nd statement was filtered and merged with the first.

When I change my approach, I forgot to use aliases for the 2nd statement. This is why the SSRS result set was empty.

M. Ali, thank you for your contribution. I'll make appropriate changes based on your feedback.